# How could I fix the build of an external crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm having trouble with the rust-postgres crate. I've included it as a dependency in my project like so:

```
[dependencies]
postgres = "0.19.4"
```

When I run `cargo build`, I get errors such as:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `futures_util::Stream`
 --> /Users/ogre/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-postgres-0.7.7/src/simple_query.rs:7:27
  |
7 | use futures_util::{ready, Stream};
  |                           ^^^^^^
  |                           |
  |                           no `Stream` in the root
  |                           help: a similar name exists in the module (notice the capitalization): `stream`
```

However, if I try cloning the rust-postgres repository, `cargo build` builds the library without any problems.

I am using the `stable-aarch64-apple-darwin` toolchain, which is updated to `rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)`

As requested, here is my `Cargo.lock` file.

```
# This file is automatically @generated by Cargo.
# It is not intended for manual editing.
version = 3

[[package]]
name = "async-trait"
version = "0.1.57"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "76464446b8bc32758d7e88ee1a804d9914cd9b1cb264c029899680b0be29826f"
dependencies = [
 "proc-macro2",
 "quote",
 "syn",
]

[[package]]
name = "autocfg"
version = "1.1.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "d468802bab17cbc0cc575e9b053f41e72aa36bfa6b7f55e3529ffa43161b97fa"

[[package]]
name = "base64"
version = "0.13.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "904dfeac50f3cdaba28fc6f57fdcddb75f49ed61346676a78c4ffe55877802fd"

[[package]]
name = "bitflags"
version = "1.3.2"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "bef38d45163c2f1dde094a7dfd33ccf595c92905c8f8f4fdc18d06fb1037718a"

[[package]]
name = "block-buffer"
version = "0.10.3"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "69cce20737498f97b993470a6e536b8523f0af7892a4f928cceb1ac5e52ebe7e"
dependencies = [
 "generic-array",
]

[[package]]
name = "byteorder"
version = "1.4.3"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "14c189c53d098945499cdfa7ecc63567cf3886b3332b312a5b4585d8d3a6a610"

[[package]]
name = "bytes"
version = "1.2.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "ec8a7b6a70fde80372154c65702f00a0f56f3e1c36abbc6c440484be248856db"

[[package]]
name = "care_plan_manager_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
dependencies = [
 "postgres",
]

[[package]]
name = "cfg-if"
version = "1.0.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "baf1de4339761588bc0619e3cbc0120ee582ebb74b53b4efbf79117bd2da40fd"

[[package]]
name = "cpufeatures"
version = "0.2.5"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "28d997bd5e24a5928dd43e46dc529867e207907fe0b239c3477d924f7f2ca320"
dependencies = [
 "libc",
]

[[package]]
name = "crypto-common"
version = "0.1.6"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "1bfb12502f3fc46cca1bb51ac28df9d618d813cdc3d2f25b9fe775a34af26bb3"
dependencies = [
 "generic-array",
 "typenum",
]

[[package]]
name = "digest"
version = "0.10.5"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "adfbc57365a37acbd2ebf2b64d7e69bb766e2fea813521ed536f5d0520dcf86c"
dependencies = [
 "block-buffer",
 "crypto-common",
 "subtle",
]

[[package]]
name = "fallible-iterator"
version = "0.2.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "4443176a9f2c162692bd3d352d745ef9413eec5782a80d8fd6f8a1ac692a07f7"

[[package]]
name = "futures-channel"
version = "0.3.24"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "30bdd20c28fadd505d0fd6712cdfcb0d4b5648baf45faef7f852afb2399bb050"
dependencies = [
 "futures-core",
 "futures-sink",
]

[[package]]
name = "futures-core"
version = "0.3.24"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "4e5aa3de05362c3fb88de6531e6296e85cde7739cccad4b9dfeeb7f6ebce56bf"

[[package]]
name = "futures-macro"
version = "0.3.24"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "42cd15d1c7456c04dbdf7e88bcd69760d74f3a798d6444e16974b505b0e62f17"
dependencies = [
 "proc-macro2",
 "quote",
 "syn",
]

[[package]]
name = "futures-sink"
version = "0.3.24"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "21b20ba5a92e727ba30e72834706623d94ac93a725410b6a6b6fbc1b07f7ba56"

[[package]]
name = "futures-task"
version = "0.3.24"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "a6508c467c73851293f390476d4491cf4d227dbabcd4170f3bb6044959b294f1"

[[package]]
name = "futures-util"
version = "0.3.24"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "44fb6cb1be61cc1d2e43b262516aafcf63b241cffdb1d3fa115f91d9c7b09c90"
dependencies = [
 "futures-core",
 "futures-macro",
 "futures-sink",
 "futures-task",
 "pin-project-lite",
 "pin-utils",
 "slab",
]

[[package]]
name = "generic-array"
version = "0.14.6"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "bff49e947297f3312447abdca79f45f4738097cc82b06e72054d2223f601f1b9"
dependencies = [
 "typenum",
 "version_check",
]

[[package]]
name = "getrandom"
version = "0.2.7"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "4eb1a864a501629691edf6c15a593b7a51eebaa1e8468e9ddc623de7c9b58ec6"
dependencies = [
 "cfg-if",
 "libc",
 "wasi",
]

[[package]]
name = "hmac"
version = "0.12.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "6c49c37c09c17a53d937dfbb742eb3a961d65a994e6bcdcf37e7399d0cc8ab5e"
dependencies = [
 "digest",
]

[[package]]
name = "libc"
version = "0.2.135"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "68783febc7782c6c5cb401fbda4de5a9898be1762314da0bb2c10ced61f18b0c"

[[package]]
name = "lock_api"
version = "0.4.9"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "435011366fe56583b16cf956f9df0095b405b82d76425bc8981c0e22e60ec4df"
dependencies = [
 "autocfg",
 "scopeguard",
]

[[package]]
name = "log"
version = "0.4.17"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "abb12e687cfb44aa40f41fc3978ef76448f9b6038cad6aef4259d3c095a2382e"
dependencies = [
 "cfg-if",
]

[[package]]
name = "md-5"
version = "0.10.5"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "6365506850d44bff6e2fbcb5176cf63650e48bd45ef2fe2665ae1570e0f4b9ca"
dependencies = [
 "digest",
]

[[package]]
name = "memchr"
version = "2.5.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "2dffe52ecf27772e601905b7522cb4ef790d2cc203488bbd0e2fe85fcb74566d"

[[package]]
name = "mio"
version = "0.8.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "57ee1c23c7c63b0c9250c339ffdc69255f110b298b901b9f6c82547b7b87caaf"
dependencies = [
 "libc",
 "log",
 "wasi",
 "windows-sys",
]

[[package]]
name = "once_cell"
version = "1.15.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "e82dad04139b71a90c080c8463fe0dc7902db5192d939bd0950f074d014339e1"

[[package]]
name = "parking_lot"
version = "0.12.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "3742b2c103b9f06bc9fff0a37ff4912935851bee6d36f3c02bcc755bcfec228f"
dependencies = [
 "lock_api",
 "parking_lot_core",
]

[[package]]
name = "parking_lot_core"
version = "0.9.3"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "09a279cbf25cb0757810394fbc1e359949b59e348145c643a939a525692e6929"
dependencies = [
 "cfg-if",
 "libc",
 "redox_syscall",
 "smallvec",
 "windows-sys",
]

[[package]]
name = "percent-encoding"
version = "2.2.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "478c572c3d73181ff3c2539045f6eb99e5491218eae919370993b890cdbdd98e"

[[package]]
name = "phf"
version = "0.11.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "928c6535de93548188ef63bb7c4036bd415cd8f36ad25af44b9789b2ee72a48c"
dependencies = [
 "phf_shared",
]

[[package]]
name = "phf_shared"
version = "0.11.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "e1fb5f6f826b772a8d4c0394209441e7d37cbbb967ae9c7e0e8134365c9ee676"
dependencies = [
 "siphasher",
]

[[package]]
name = "pin-project-lite"
version = "0.2.9"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "e0a7ae3ac2f1173085d398531c705756c94a4c56843785df85a60c1a0afac116"

[[package]]
name = "pin-utils"
version = "0.1.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "8b870d8c151b6f2fb93e84a13146138f05d02ed11c7e7c54f8826aaaf7c9f184"

[[package]]
name = "postgres"
version = "0.19.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "960c214283ef8f0027974c03e9014517ced5db12f021a9abb66185a5751fab0a"
dependencies = [
 "bytes",
 "fallible-iterator",
 "futures-util",
 "log",
 "tokio",
 "tokio-postgres",
]

[[package]]
name = "postgres-protocol"
version = "0.6.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "878c6cbf956e03af9aa8204b407b9cbf47c072164800aa918c516cd4b056c50c"
dependencies = [
 "base64",
 "byteorder",
 "bytes",
 "fallible-iterator",
 "hmac",
 "md-5",
 "memchr",
 "rand",
 "sha2",
 "stringprep",
]

[[package]]
name = "postgres-types"
version = "0.2.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "73d946ec7d256b04dfadc4e6a3292324e6f417124750fc5c0950f981b703a0f1"
dependencies = [
 "bytes",
 "fallible-iterator",
 "postgres-protocol",
]

[[package]]
name = "ppv-lite86"
version = "0.2.16"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "eb9f9e6e233e5c4a35559a617bf40a4ec447db2e84c20b55a6f83167b7e57872"

[[package]]
name = "proc-macro2"
version = "1.0.47"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "5ea3d908b0e36316caf9e9e2c4625cdde190a7e6f440d794667ed17a1855e725"
dependencies = [
 "unicode-ident",
]

[[package]]
name = "quote"
version = "1.0.21"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "bbe448f377a7d6961e30f5955f9b8d106c3f5e449d493ee1b125c1d43c2b5179"
dependencies = [
 "proc-macro2",
]

[[package]]
name = "rand"
version = "0.8.5"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "34af8d1a0e25924bc5b7c43c079c942339d8f0a8b57c39049bef581b46327404"
dependencies = [
 "libc",
 "rand_chacha",
 "rand_core",
]

[[package]]
name = "rand_chacha"
version = "0.3.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "e6c10a63a0fa32252be49d21e7709d4d4baf8d231c2dbce1eaa8141b9b127d88"
dependencies = [
 "ppv-lite86",
 "rand_core",
]

[[package]]
name = "rand_core"
version = "0.6.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "ec0be4795e2f6a28069bec0b5ff3e2ac9bafc99e6a9a7dc3547996c5c816922c"
dependencies = [
 "getrandom",
]

[[package]]
name = "redox_syscall"
version = "0.2.16"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "fb5a58c1855b4b6819d59012155603f0b22ad30cad752600aadfcb695265519a"
dependencies = [
 "bitflags",
]

[[package]]
name = "scopeguard"
version = "1.1.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "d29ab0c6d3fc0ee92fe66e2d99f700eab17a8d57d1c1d3b748380fb20baa78cd"

[[package]]
name = "sha2"
version = "0.10.6"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "82e6b795fe2e3b1e845bafcb27aa35405c4d47cdfc92af5fc8d3002f76cebdc0"
dependencies = [
 "cfg-if",
 "cpufeatures",
 "digest",
]

[[package]]
name = "siphasher"
version = "0.3.10"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "7bd3e3206899af3f8b12af284fafc038cc1dc2b41d1b89dd17297221c5d225de"

[[package]]
name = "slab"
version = "0.4.7"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "4614a76b2a8be0058caa9dbbaf66d988527d86d003c11a94fbd335d7661edcef"
dependencies = [
 "autocfg",
]

[[package]]
name = "smallvec"
version = "1.10.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "a507befe795404456341dfab10cef66ead4c041f62b8b11bbb92bffe5d0953e0"

[[package]]
name = "socket2"
version = "0.4.7"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "02e2d2db9033d13a1567121ddd7a095ee144db4e1ca1b1bda3419bc0da294ebd"
dependencies = [
 "libc",
 "winapi",
]

[[package]]
name = "stringprep"
version = "0.1.2"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "8ee348cb74b87454fff4b551cbf727025810a004f88aeacae7f85b87f4e9a1c1"
dependencies = [
 "unicode-bidi",
 "unicode-normalization",
]

[[package]]
name = "subtle"
version = "2.4.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "6bdef32e8150c2a081110b42772ffe7d7c9032b606bc226c8260fd97e0976601"

[[package]]
name = "syn"
version = "1.0.102"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "3fcd952facd492f9be3ef0d0b7032a6e442ee9b361d4acc2b1d0c4aaa5f613a1"
dependencies = [
 "proc-macro2",
 "quote",
 "unicode-ident",
]

[[package]]
name = "tinyvec"
version = "1.6.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "87cc5ceb3875bb20c2890005a4e226a4651264a5c75edb2421b52861a0a0cb50"
dependencies = [
 "tinyvec_macros",
]

[[package]]
name = "tinyvec_macros"
version = "0.1.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "cda74da7e1a664f795bb1f8a87ec406fb89a02522cf6e50620d016add6dbbf5c"

[[package]]
name = "tokio"
version = "1.21.2"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "a9e03c497dc955702ba729190dc4aac6f2a0ce97f913e5b1b5912fc5039d9099"
dependencies = [
 "autocfg",
 "bytes",
 "libc",
 "memchr",
 "mio",
 "pin-project-lite",
 "socket2",
 "winapi",
]

[[package]]
name = "tokio-postgres"
version = "0.7.7"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "29a12c1b3e0704ae7dfc25562629798b29c72e6b1d0a681b6f29ab4ae5e7f7bf"
dependencies = [
 "async-trait",
 "byteorder",
 "bytes",
 "fallible-iterator",
 "futures-channel",
 "futures-util",
 "log",
 "parking_lot",
 "percent-encoding",
 "phf",
 "pin-project-lite",
 "postgres-protocol",
 "postgres-types",
 "socket2",
 "tokio",
 "tokio-util",
]

[[package]]
name = "tokio-util"
version = "0.7.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "0bb2e075f03b3d66d8d8785356224ba688d2906a371015e225beeb65ca92c740"
dependencies = [
 "bytes",
 "futures-core",
 "futures-sink",
 "pin-project-lite",
 "tokio",
 "tracing",
]

[[package]]
name = "tracing"
version = "0.1.37"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "8ce8c33a8d48bd45d624a6e523445fd21ec13d3653cd51f681abf67418f54eb8"
dependencies = [
 "cfg-if",
 "pin-project-lite",
 "tracing-core",
]

[[package]]
name = "tracing-core"
version = "0.1.30"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "24eb03ba0eab1fd845050058ce5e616558e8f8d8fca633e6b163fe25c797213a"
dependencies = [
 "once_cell",
]

[[package]]
name = "typenum"
version = "1.15.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "dcf81ac59edc17cc8697ff311e8f5ef2d99fcbd9817b34cec66f90b6c3dfd987"

[[package]]
name = "unicode-bidi"
version = "0.3.8"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "099b7128301d285f79ddd55b9a83d5e6b9e97c92e0ea0daebee7263e932de992"

[[package]]
name = "unicode-ident"
version = "1.0.5"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "6ceab39d59e4c9499d4e5a8ee0e2735b891bb7308ac83dfb4e80cad195c9f6f3"

[[package]]
name = "unicode-normalization"
version = "0.1.22"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "5c5713f0fc4b5db668a2ac63cdb7bb4469d8c9fed047b1d0292cc7b0ce2ba921"
dependencies = [
 "tinyvec",
]

[[package]]
name = "version_check"
version = "0.9.4"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "49874b5167b65d7193b8aba1567f5c7d93d001cafc34600cee003eda787e483f"

[[package]]
name = "wasi"
version = "0.11.0+wasi-snapshot-preview1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "9c8d87e72b64a3b4db28d11ce29237c246188f4f51057d65a7eab63b7987e423"

[[package]]
name = "winapi"
version = "0.3.9"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "5c839a674fcd7a98952e593242ea400abe93992746761e38641405d28b00f419"
dependencies = [
 "winapi-i686-pc-windows-gnu",
 "winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu",
]

[[package]]
name = "winapi-i686-pc-windows-gnu"
version = "0.4.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "ac3b87c63620426dd9b991e5ce0329eff545bccbbb34f3be09ff6fb6ab51b7b6"

[[package]]
name = "winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"
version = "0.4.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "712e227841d057c1ee1cd2fb22fa7e5a5461ae8e48fa2ca79ec42cfc1931183f"

[[package]]
name = "windows-sys"
version = "0.36.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "ea04155a16a59f9eab786fe12a4a450e75cdb175f9e0d80da1e17db09f55b8d2"
dependencies = [
 "windows_aarch64_msvc",
 "windows_i686_gnu",
 "windows_i686_msvc",
 "windows_x86_64_gnu",
 "windows_x86_64_msvc",
]

[[package]]
name = "windows_aarch64_msvc"
version = "0.36.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "9bb8c3fd39ade2d67e9874ac4f3db21f0d710bee00fe7cab16949ec184eeaa47"

[[package]]
name = "windows_i686_gnu"
version = "0.36.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "180e6ccf01daf4c426b846dfc66db1fc518f074baa793aa7d9b9aaeffad6a3b6"

[[package]]
name = "windows_i686_msvc"
version = "0.36.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "e2e7917148b2812d1eeafaeb22a97e4813dfa60a3f8f78ebe204bcc88f12f024"

[[package]]
name = "windows_x86_64_gnu"
version = "0.36.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "4dcd171b8776c41b97521e5da127a2d86ad280114807d0b2ab1e462bc764d9e1"

[[package]]
name = "windows_x86_64_msvc"
version = "0.36.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "c811ca4a8c853ef420abd8592ba53ddbbac90410fab6903b3e79972a631f7680"
```

What might be the problem here, and what could be tried to solve it?

Comment: I just tried and got (different) errors with those crates. Downgrading to `"=0.19.3"` fixed it for me.

Comment: I guess that a maintainer of one of the dependencies has been careless with semver. You should report this as a bug in the `postgres` crate repository.

Comment: Interestingly, I just updated my Rust toolchain, and that also fixed it - even with version 0.19.4. No idea why, but you could try that too.

Comment: Can you share your `Cargo.lock`? Maybe your project is pulling in an older `futures-util`.

Comment: Toolchain update hints that `resolver = 2` could probably fix it, either.

Comment: @PeterHall, I have reported this issue, and tried the suggestions given there: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/956
I'll add some updates to the question with a bit more information about the toolchain.

Comment: @Cerberus, I just tried setting `resolver = "2"`, but that hasn't changed the result.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, I wasn't paying enough attention when I started getting different errors. I seem to have solved the problem somehow, but I'm not sure what it was that did it.

Comment: Which macOS version are you using? I think there is a bug out there with the `rust 1.64.0` for some old macOS version.